# How to change navigation of custom sliding menu

Tags: android, slidingmenu, android-sliding

I am trying my custom sliding navigation. I know there are already lot's of tutorial or library is available but this is for my own purpose.

So basically i am trying to open sliding menu and it is opening `left to right` now i want to change it's direction from `right to left`. How can i do this.

Below is my code.

```
public class Profile extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

    private int windowWidth;
    boolean alreadyShowing = false;
    private Animation mAnimation;
    LayoutInflater mLayoutInflater;
    private RelativeLayout mRelativeLayout;

    ImageView sliding_menu;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.profile);

        Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
        windowWidth = display.getWidth();
        display.getHeight();
        mLayoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        sliding_menu = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.slidingMenu);
        sliding_menu.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {

                if (!alreadyShowing) {
                    alreadyShowing = true;
                    openSlidingMenu();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    private void openSlidingMenu() {

        int width = (int) (windowWidth * 0.8f);
        translateView((float) (width));
        int height = LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT;
        final View layout = mLayoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.settings,
                (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.setting));

        final PopupWindow optionsPopup = new PopupWindow(layout, width, height,
                true);
        optionsPopup.setBackgroundDrawable(new PaintDrawable());
        optionsPopup.showAtLocation(layout, Gravity.NO_GRAVITY, 0, 0);
        optionsPopup.setOnDismissListener(new PopupWindow.OnDismissListener() {
            public void onDismiss() {
                cleanUp();
                translateView(0);
                cleanUp();
                alreadyShowing = false;
            }
        });
    }

    private void translateView(float right) {
        mAnimation = new TranslateAnimation(0f, right, 0f, 0f);
        mAnimation.setDuration(100);
        mAnimation.setFillEnabled(true);
        mAnimation.setFillAfter(true);

        mRelativeLayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.profile);
        mRelativeLayout.startAnimation(mAnimation);
        mRelativeLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }

    private void cleanUp() {
        if (null != mRelativeLayout) {
            mRelativeLayout.clearAnimation();
            mRelativeLayout = null;
        }
        if (null != mAnimation) {
            mAnimation.cancel();
            mAnimation = null;
        }
    }
```

[image]

So basically you can see in above image that my menu is opening from `left to right`, how can i change it from `right to left`.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Take a look at this library: https://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu

Comment: @yahya is right look this one

Comment: Take a look at the default Navigation Drawer pattern. It works very nice, follows the guidelines and is very customizable. https://developer.android.com/design/patterns/navigation-drawer.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have solved this question, i have just changed gravity to right side of this below line and it is working now.

```
optionsPopup.showAtLocation(layout, Gravity.RIGHT, 0, 0);
```

So before change my code was something like this.

```
final PopupWindow optionsPopup = new PopupWindow(layout, width, height,true);
optionsPopup.setBackgroundDrawable(new PaintDrawable());
optionsPopup.showAtLocation(layout, Gravity.NO_GRAVITY, 0, 0);
```

and now it is like below

```
final PopupWindow optionsPopup = new PopupWindow(layout, width, height,true);
optionsPopup.setBackgroundDrawable(new PaintDrawable());
optionsPopup.showAtLocation(layout, Gravity.RIGHT, 0, 0);
```

Thank you all for helping me.